# com tranformação

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
def eR(k,x):

    if k<=1:

     return 1
    else:
        return (x**k)/eR(k-1,x)*k

x=int(input("Insira o X:"))

k=int(input("Insira o número de termos:"))

print(eR(k,x))
```

Comment: o codigo recursivo eu fiz mas iterativo nao consigo pois atribui o k= k-1 para fazer fatorial troca  a variável de x**k ae da um resultado diferente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def eR(k, x):
    result = 1
    for kp in range(2, k + 1):
        result = (x ** kp) / result * kp
    return result
```

Com while:

```
def eR(k, x):
    kp = result = 1
    while kp < k:
        kp += 1
        result = (x ** kp) / result * kp
    return result
```

Comment: mas ta exibindo resultado diferente da recursiva

Comment: @marcelo ops, já editei a resposta, faltou um `+1`

Comment: vc usou o for como fazer  com while ou com if tem como fazer me da uma ideia

Comment: @marcelo coloquei com `while` na resposta

Comment: deu certo  vlw obrigado entendi como vc fez vou fazer o proximo